# Any command by which i can go directly to the specify path via command line in window

Tags: cmd, windows-xp

Is there any solution or command by which i can directly go to that bin directory which i saw in the image. Like i set the full path in some variable and execute that variable in cmd and that set the path. Because i need to set that path after every 20 or 30 minute  [image: path of bin directory]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this line into a batchfile somewhere in your path (e.g. `home.bat`):

```
@cd /d "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin"
```

Whenever you type `home`, it will change your working directory.

Comment: Thanks , It  works for me . I need to run the home.bat file first.

Comment: I need to go the Root Directory first then execute that 'home' variable which is the name of bat file. Is there any solution by which i can directly go to desire path from any diretory path.

Comment: yes: "put this line into a batchfile **somewhere in your path**"

Comment: ok. It works for me. But for that i need to go to **c:\>** first then it works. But What if i am in **c:\windows\system32>** this path?

Comment: "somewhere in your path" means into a directory listed in `%path%`. When I interprete you right, you put it into `c:\`. I would be surprised, if `c:\` happens to be in `%path%`. You could add it, but I suggest using an own directory for that (maybe `c:\mytools\`)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd "Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin"
```

would seem to work.

As would

```
pushd "Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.39\bin"
```

altough the latter uses a `CMD` internal stack but has the advantage that executing a `POPD` would return to the original directory.